# My content cannot be shown properly inside the v-textarea in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I am now using v-textarea and auto-grow to create an input area.
Here's the screenshot of my input area:
[Keyboard scrolled Input area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y9Sk.png)

When I use my keyboard to scroll up the input area, the texts cannot be completely shown. However, when I use mouse to scroll up the input area, the texts can be fully shown just like this:
[Mouse scrolled Input area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vRMR.png)

I have tried to add a negative padding to top of the input area, but it becomes more weierd:

```
.v-textarea--auto-grow .v-field__input {
    --v-field-padding-top: -20px;
  }
```

I also find the similar problem on the github bug report:  [VTextarea has a wrong calculated height on autoGrow](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/15375). But they seems already fixed the bug and update into the vuetify.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?